# Failing to upload to amazon s3 bucket using Perl and WWW::Curl::Easy

Tags: perl, amazon-s3, curl

I'm trying to upload an jpeg file to amazon S3 bucket using this perl code:

```perl
    my $curl =  WWW::Curl::Easy->new();

    $curl_headers->[0] = sprintf 'Content-Type:%s', $extra_headers->{'Content-Type'};
    $curl_headers->[1] = sprintf 'Content-MD5:%s', $extra_headers->{'Content-MD5'};
    $curl_headers->[2] = sprintf 'Content-Disposition:%s', $extra_headers->{'Content-Disposition'};
    $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_HEADER,       1);
    $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS,   1);
    $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $curl_headers);
    $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,  'PUT');
    $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE_LARGE, $size + 0);
    $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_READDATA, \$image_fh); # cgi temp file file handle
    $curl->perform();
```

And get this error message:

```
403 Forbidden
403 Forbidden
.............
Server: AmazonS3

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided.
```

If ran this curl in the terminal with the same url and headers it works:

```
curl -X PUT \
-H "Content-Type:image/jpeg" \
-H "Content-MD5:file_checksum" \
-H "Content-Disposition:inline; filename=\"Tesla-Model-3-600x350-1.jpeg\"; filename*=UTF-8''Tesla-Model-3-600x350-1.jpeg" \
-T Tesla-Model-3-600x350-1.jpeg \
URL
```

Comment: Maybe try to debug using [`CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Curl::Easy) ?

Answer (score 1):

I have used LWP::UserAgent for this:

```perl
use LWP::UserAgent;
use  HTTP::Request;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();

my $request_obj = HTTP::Request->new( 'PUT', $url, [
            'Content-Type'  => $extra_headers->{'Content-Type'},
            'Content-MD5'   => $extra_headers->{'Content-MD5'},
            'Content-Disposition' => $extra_headers->{'Content-Disposition'},
        ],
        _read_binary_file($file, $size);
    );

my $res = $ua->request($request_obj);   

sub _read_binary_file {
    my ($file, $size) = @_;

    open  (my $fh, '<:raw', $file) or die "can not open $file: $!";

    my $success = read $fh, my $cont, $size + 0;
    die $! if not defined $success;

    return $cont;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Uploading a file to S3 without a signature is not possible. To proceed, please utilize the AWS SDK in Perl to generate the required signature using your access and secret keys.

```
use Net::Amazon::S3;
use MIME::Types;

my $bucket_name = 'your-bucket-name';
my $access_key = 'your-access-key';
my $secret_key = 'your-secret-key';

my $filename = 'image.jpg';
my $key = 'path/to/image.jpg';

my $s3 = Net::Amazon::S3->new(
{
    aws_access_key_id     => $access_key,
    aws_secret_access_key => $secret_key,
    retry                 => 1,
});

my $bucket = $s3->bucket($bucket_name);

my $content_type = MIME::Types->new->mimeTypeOf($filename);

my $object = $bucket->put_filename(
   $key,
   $filename,
   {
     'Content-Type' => $content_type,
   }
);
print $object
```